# how to select 2nd <LI> element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, how can I dynamically change one of the list-items below from this:

```
<ul class="tabbernav">
<li class="tabberactive"><a title="All">All</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="One">One</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="Two">Two</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="Three">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul class="tabbernav">
<li class="tabberactive"><a title="All">All</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="One">One</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="Two">-----------NEW LIST ITEM CHANGED---------</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="Three">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Careful with the language, you're actually asking the third item, which is the item at index=2

Answer (score 7):

I guess you could use getElementsByTagName inside of the ul to get all your list items inside an array. Then you can just edit the third element in your array, with index number 2.

```
var lItems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul").getElementsByTagName("li");
lItems[2].innerHTML = "<a title='Two'>----NEW LIST ITEM CHANGED-----</a>";
```

That will ofcourse get all ul elements on the page, and might lead to some strange results if you have more than two uls in your document. But you get the idea, right? Just ask some more if you don't understand what I'm trying to say.

Okay, the above code doesn't really work properly. I've modified my code a bit, but that also included a change in your HTML, as i presume you'll only have one ul "tabbernav", thus I changed it from `class="tabbernav"` to `id="tabbernav"`. This is the code to do what you want.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("tabbernav");
var liArray = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < liArray.length; i++) {
    if(liArray[i].childNodes[0].title == "Two") {
        liArray[i].innerHTML = "Your desired output";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you some more :)

Comment: See my comment about DOM array ordering on Kevin's post. I'm not sure this is safe for cross-browser use.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it after posting. I guess you could loop through the array looking for child nodes where title="Two" to avoid that problem.

Comment: I think getelements is actually x-safe, but I'm not 100% on chrome. If it isn't it would be better to invoke xpath selection for !IE.

Comment: @Jesper - easier to start at firstChild and loop nextSibling N times

Comment: The code in this answer is fine, but it's probably not cross-browser compatible. See Jesper's comment after mine, though, about looping through the array looking for child nodes with title="Two". That's more like what you should do.

Comment: @TeddyK12: I just edited my answer, see if that helps you along some more :)

Answer (score 6):

I also suggest using jQuery, which makes selections like this trivial. In your case, you can use the :eq psuedo-selector to get the second line element:

```
$('.tabbernav li:eq(1)')
```

This selects the DOM element which is the *second* li (indexes start at 0) in an element with the class tabbernav. It returns a jQuery object which you can chain other methods to. Changing the inner HTML is done with .html('Your html here').

Answer (score 2):

This is how you select the third Li element of your Ul list in pure JavaScript.

```
document.querySelectorAll("li")[2].innerHTML = "vasile";
```

Replace "Vasile" with your desired text.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
list[2].innerHTML = "<a title='Two'>------NEW LIST ITEM CHANGED----</a>";
```

this will work perfect

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old but since it's still open, see how I modified the first answer. I feel someone else might need it.

```
>var lItems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
>>var nth = lItems.getElementsByTagName("li")[2];
>>>nth.innerHTML = "<a title='Two'>----NEW LIST ITEM CHANGED-----> </a>";
```

So that basically solves it up by specifying the position of the lItems in particular to grab and in this case [0]. The code will not work properly if that position is missing because getElementsByTagName(NAME) returns a collection of html elements bearing that NAME specified. So that if you don't specify which among them all, the code fails.

If you like code reuse, see a function you can use for that. You just need to specify the parent element and its position and the childNode position and you get the same thing.

```
>var nthChild = function(parent, pos, childPos){
>>parent = document.getElementsByTagName(parent)[pos];
>>>return parent.children[childPos];
>>>>};
//used thus:
>nthChild("ul", 0, 2).innerHTML = "<a title='Two'>----NEW LIST ITEM CHANGED-----> </a>
```

---

";

Answer (score 0):

How do you identify which `<li>` is the one you want to modify?

If you're doing it by index you could do something like this I think:

```
var list = document.getElementById("listid");
list.childNodes[2].innerHtml = "<a title='Two'>-----------NEW LIST ITEM CHANGED---------</a>";
```

Comment: I'm not sure about childNodes here, but I know that browsers don't guarantee an order of certain DOM arrays. For example, using IE8 in IE7 rendering mode (I believe) messes up some of the array ordering you might expect. Either way, the location of a node in a DOM array isn't guaranteed to be the same order as defined in the HTML.

Comment: @Marc W - no kidding!  Thanks for the tip :).

Comment: iirc childNodes won't be x-browser safe because in !IE browsers textnodes are included

Answer (score -2):

Look into using a Javascript library such as JQuery. That will make your life a lot easier. Then you can do something like this:

```
$('li a[title=Two]').text('Changed Text Goes Here');
```

You'll need to check my syntax (not sure about the `text()` function), but it's easy enough to look up in JQuery's api docs.

Comment: How would I do this without JQuery?